# java.lang.AbstractMethodError while using Jersey rest webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I have a webservice which I am using to receive multipart/form data from UI. My POM file is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> <!-- only on client side -->
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.29</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aerospike</groupId>
        <artifactId>aerospike-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans-xpath</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/saxon-dom -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>saxon-dom</artifactId>
        <version>8.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.dom4j.dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I try to run the UI and webservice in tomcat 8 I receive the error. **java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;**

I checked most of the SO questions related to this exception and tried all the suggestions but none of them work for me. I am stuck here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding in case it someone face the issue. I resolved the issue by following this [link](https://tonyyan.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-javax-ws-rs-core-uribuilder-uri/)